# Parenting rig to empties

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

I am trying to parent individual parts of a rig (bones) to specific empties which are already animated so I can get the rig to be moved by the animated empties. I have attached a screenshot. The empties are in the form of an animated face. Problem is, when I click on  the rig to parent to an empty, it is selecting the whole rig rather than the part of the rig I want. How do I make it select a specific part of the rig and not the whole thing?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can parent empties to bones, but not the other way.  If you want the bone to follow the empty,

- go into pose mode,
- select the bone,
- go to Bone Constraints in the properties panel
- Add a Damped Track constraint
- Select the empty as the target

[image: Sample Damped Track Constraint]